# Using HID barcode scanner with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dll, hid

Is there a simple dll library/assembly that I can add as a reference to my 2019 visual basic program that will provide methods (or a form control so events such as receiving data could be easily handled) to access my HID USB scanner? I'm using the scanner as a HID, not as a keyboard wedge. I have tried 'Windows.Devices.HumanInterfaceDevice.dll' with no luck. When I try to add as a reference. Visual studios tells me to please make sure that it is a valid assembly. It doesn't like it - after some reading it seems that it is a UWP library and can only be used in a UWP project. Again, is there a simple 'dll' library that I can add to my simple winform 2019 visual basic program that will provide methods to access my HID USB scanner? Is it unreasonable that I would expect there to be such a library/assembly/reference?

Comment: It is reasonable to expect that such a thing exists, but there is no guarantee. Check the Datasheet and other documentation that you should have available, or can obtain from -, the device manufacturer. At the least it should contain information on how you should communicate with the device.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question though as it is not a specific question about programming.

Comment: Then where should I have posted a question dealing with adding a reference to a visual basic .net project?

Comment: You should try on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). If you decide to post your question there i'd advise you to also put the model number and manufacturer of your device in the question, along with any other relevant information.